# Request method 'POST' not supported]

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem with updatePowerPlant() method, when I try to update powerPlant entity with given id and click the submit button in the update form under localhost:8080/updatePowerPlant adress I get redirected to this url http://localhost:8080/updatePowerPlant/savePowerPlant.

I don't know why. I should get redireted to /powerPlants, wethever entity with given id exists or not, instead /savePowerPlant is added as a last part of a url localhost:8080/updatePowerPlant and I get  Request method 'POST' not supported], I know that this is the message I should get afterall there is no GetController with such url but why do I get this weird url? Is it because I use GetController for update?

localhost:8080/updatePowerPlant this I enter in browser to get update form
http://localhost:8080/updatePowerPlant/savePowerPlant this I get when I clik submit in update form

Controller class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class PowerPlantsController {


    private final PowerPlantRepository powerPlantRepository;
    private final EventRepository eventRepository;
    private final PlantService plantService;
    private final EventService eventService;


    @GetMapping("form")
    public String getForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("plant", new PlantViewModel());
        return "save";
    }


    @PostMapping("savePowerPlant")
    public String addPowerPlant(@ModelAttribute("plant") @Valid PlantViewModel plant, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            if (plant.getId() == null) {
                return "save";
            } else return "updatePowerPlant";
        }
        if (plant.getId() == null){
            plantService.add(plant);
        }else {
            plantService.update(plant);
        }
        return "redirect:/powerPlants";
    }


    @GetMapping("updatePowerPlant/{id}")
    public String updatePowerPlant(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id, Model model) {
        var find = powerPlantRepository.getOne(id);
        var plants = plantService.powerPlantToViewModel(find);
        model.addAttribute("plant", plants);
        return "updatePowerPlant";
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("failures/{id}")
    public long failures(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return eventService.NumberOfFailureEventsForId(id);
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("powerPlants")
    public List<PowerPlant> findAll() {
        return powerPlantRepository.findAll();
    }


    @GetMapping("powerPlants/{id}")
    public String findById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("plant", powerPlantRepository.getOne(id));

        return "plant";
    }


    @GetMapping("delete/powerPlants")
    public String deleteById(@RequestParam(value = "id") Integer id) {
        powerPlantRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/powerPlants";
    }

    @GetMapping("addEventToPlant")
    public String addEventToPlant(@RequestParam(value = "plantId") Long plantId, @RequestParam(value = "eventId")
            Long eventId, Model model) {


        if (powerPlantRepository.findById(Math.toIntExact(plantId)).isPresent()
                && eventRepository.findById(Math.toIntExact(eventId)).isPresent()) {
            var pl = powerPlantRepository.getOne(Math.toIntExact(plantId));
            var ev = eventRepository.getOne(Math.toIntExact(eventId));

            var eventsForPlant = pl.getEvents();
            eventsForPlant.add(ev);
            pl.setEvents(eventsForPlant);

            powerPlantRepository.save(pl);
        }

        var t = powerPlantRepository.getOne(Math.toIntExact(plantId)).getEvents();
        model.addAttribute("plant", t);

        return "plant_events";
    }
}
```

Service class

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlantService implements powerForPowerPlantPerDay, Add, PlantServiceToViewModel {


    private final EventRepository eventRepository;
    private final PowerPlantRepository powerPlantRepository;

    public Map<Integer, String> powerForPowerPlantPerDay(Timestamp date) {
        List<Event> list = new ArrayList<>(getAllEvents());
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        list.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.startDate.equals(date))
                .forEach(e -> map.put(e.id, e.typeOfEvent));
        return map;
    }


    public Collection<Event> getAllEvents() {
        return eventRepository.findAll();
    }


    public void add(PlantViewModel plantViewModel) {
        var p = PowerPlant.builder().
                name(plantViewModel.getName())
                .power(plantViewModel.getPower())
                .events(plantViewModel.getListOfEventsForPlant())
                .build();
        powerPlantRepository.save(p);
    }

    public PlantViewModel powerPlantToViewModel(PowerPlant powerPlant) {
        return PlantViewModel.builder()
                .id(powerPlant.getId())
                .name(powerPlant.getName())
                .power(powerPlant.getPower())
                .build();

    }


    public PowerPlant update(PlantViewModel plantViewModel) {
        var plant = powerPlantRepository.getOne(plantViewModel.getId());

        plant.setName(plantViewModel.getName());
        plant.setPower(plantViewModel.getPower());

        return powerPlantRepository.save(plant);
    }
}
```

update html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Update</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>Update powerPlant</h2>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{savePowerPlant}" th:object="${plant}" method="POST">
        <input id="studentId" th:value="${plant.id}" type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Invalid Name</div>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('power')}" th:errors="*{power}">Invalid power</div>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{power}" placeholder="power" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

save html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Student</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Save</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>Save powerPlant</h2>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{savePowerPlant}" th:object="${plant}" method="POST">
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Invalid Name</div>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('power')}" th:errors="*{power}">Invalid power</div>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{power}" placeholder="power" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) in the documentation you are using relative URLs in your `th:action`. These get appended to the current URL in the address bar.

So `th:action="@{savePowerPlant}"` results in `current/URL/savePowerPlant`.

Simple solution is to switch to absolute URLs either by typing it out completely (`http://localhost:portNumber/savePowerPlant`) or perhaps even better use server relative URL: `th:href="@{~/savePowerPlant}`.

Comment: @J Asgarov thanks

Comment: @user17563398 if this answers your question please accept the answer so people having similar problem can easier find the answer